# How to show/hide table row <tr> in .ascx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, html

I tried this, but could not get through:-

code behind

```
protected HtmlTableRow trComment;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Show/Hide table rows (TR)
    trComment.Visible = ConfigUtil.DisplaySummaryComment;
}
```

.ascx page

```
<tr id="trComment" runat="server">
    <td style="vertical-align:top; text-align:left;">
        <%#ConfigUtil.FieldLabels["PIComments"]%>
        :
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Test.Comment %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your original code doesn't work, not because it's incorrect, but because you probably have more places with `trComment` (in which case it should error) or because your current code is inside a template of some sort (in a `GridView`, a `Repeater`). The latter is most likely, because you use a data-statement (`<%#`), which is commonly placed in a databound control template (but not necessarily).

One way to solve this uniformly and easily (many ways exist and it's probably best not to use literal tables anyway) is to use an `asp:PlaceHolder`, which does not leave HTML "traces", but can be used to toggle any block of HTML / ASP.NET code:

```
<!-- toggle through OnLoad (can use ID as well) -->
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" OnLoad="MakeVisibleOrNot">
    <tr>
       ...
    </
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

in the code behind

```
protected void MakeVisibleOrNot(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Control) sender).Visible = ConfigUtil.DisplaySummaryComment;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<tr id="trComment" runat="server">
   <td>

   </td>
</tr>
```

Then in your Page_Load() method find your element and set visibility true or false like below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   trComment.Visible = false; //or trComment.Visible = true; as you wish
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
trComment.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: the `.Visible` in ASP.NET prevents rendering of that control completely. If that doesn't work, `display:none;` doesn't either.

Answer (score 0):

This also works with no code behind

```
                        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible ='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Session["sess_isArtist"].ToString() == "1" || Session["sess_isBeneficiary"].ToString() == "1" ? "true": "false") %>'>
<tr>
   ...
</
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
```